# Need specific sets of columns to be converted into a row and the rest of columns to repeat values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, data-cleaning

I have data in the following format

| ID | SCHOOL | Name1 | Name1 Subject1 | Name1 Grade1 | Name1 Subject2 | Name1 Grade2 | Name2 | Name2 Subject1 | Name2 Grade1 | Name2 Subject2 | Name2 Grade2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | S1 | Mr. ABC | Math | 6 | Science | 7 | Mr. XYZ | Social | 8 | EVS | 9 |
| 2 | S2 | Mr. PQR | Math | 10 | Science | 11 | Mr. KLM | Social | 8 | EVS | 9 |

Can I transform it in the following format using **Python**

| ID | SCHOOL | Name | Subject | Grade |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | S1 | Mr. ABC | Math | 6 |
| 1 | S1 | Mr. ABC | Science | 7 |
| 1 | S1 | Mr. XYZ | Social | 8 |
| 1 | S1 | Mr. XYZ | EVS | 9 |
| 2 | S2 | Mr. PQR | Math | 10 |
| 2 | S2 | Mr. PQR | Science | 11 |
| 2 | S2 | Mr. KLM | Social | 8 |
| 2 | S2 | Mr. KLM | EVS | 9 |

Comment: What is the logic you are trying to apply ?

Comment: @kgkmeekg To make things easier I changed 'Name1' to 'Name1 Instance1' and similarly added  'Name1 Instance2', 'Name2 Instance1' and so on. Then, I collated them in a list and applied pandas' melt function and then distributed the value column into these, but I wanted to know if some other way is possible.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there might be a nicer solution but this also works:

```
df_1=df[['ID', 'SCHOOL','Name1', 'Name1 Subject1',
       'Name1 Grade1']]
df_2=df[['ID', 'SCHOOL','Name1', 'Name1 Subject2',
       'Name1 Grade2']]

df_3=df[['ID', 'SCHOOL','Name2', 'Name2 Subject1',
       'Name2 Grade1']]

df_4=df[['ID', 'SCHOOL','Name2', 'Name2 Subject2',
       'Name2 Grade2']]

df_list=[df_1,df_2,df_3,df_4]
for i in df_list:
    i.columns=['ID','SCHOOL','Name','Subject','Grade']
final=pd.concat(df_list)
print(final)
'''
    ID  SCHOOL  Name    Subject Grade
0   1   S1      Mr. ABC Math    6
1   2   S2      Mr. PQR Math    10
0   1   S1      Mr. ABC Science 7
1   2   S2      Mr. PQR Science 11
0   1   S1      Mr. XYZ Social  8
1   2   S2      Mr. KLM Social  8
0   1   S1      Mr. XYZ EVS     9
1   2   S2      Mr. KLM EVS     9

'''
```

Comment: Thanks, it helped to get to the solution

Answer (score 0):

One option is with [pivot_longer](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.pivot.pivot_longer) from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/):

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd
import janitor


(df
.pivot_longer(
    index = ['ID', 'SCHOOL', 'Name1', 'Name2'], 
    names_to = ('name', '.value'), 
    names_pattern=r"(.+)\s(.+)\d", 
    sort_by_appearance=True)
.assign(Name = lambda df: np.where(df.name.eq('Name1'), df.Name1, df.Name2))
.loc[:, ['ID', 'SCHOOL', 'Name', 'Subject', 'Grade']]
)

   ID SCHOOL     Name  Subject  Grade
0   1     S1  Mr. ABC     Math      6
1   1     S1  Mr. ABC  Science      7
2   1     S1  Mr. XYZ   Social      8
3   1     S1  Mr. XYZ      EVS      9
4   2     S2  Mr. PQR     Math     10
5   2     S2  Mr. PQR  Science     11
6   2     S2  Mr. KLM   Social      8
7   2     S2  Mr. KLM      EVS      9
```

The `names_pattern` is a regex to capture groups within the specified columns. Groups are specified in the parenthesis; any group that aligns with `.value` stays as column header. here we have two groups in the names_pattern and two values in names_to, the second group is paired with `.value` and stays as a column header.

After reshaping, the where clause helps to ensure correct match and final output